# delete in adjacency table

Tags: php, adjacency-list

I have an adjacency table with parent and child elements and when I delete my parent element I would like to delete all his child.

**My table:**

```
id   name   parent
1    Name1  null
2    SubName1 1
```

When I'm trying to delete row with id=1 I would like to delete and id=2
How can I do this?

My table:

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cats` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `parent` (`parent`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: *Is* this a database table?

Comment: That's not correct, it should be "his or her child". Unless you are using a Mac then it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys could be the solution.
How you create them is dependent on your used Database.

At foreign keys there is a primary key defined which is like a "parent", if the parent gets deleted the childs get deleted to if you define it.

Comment: "When I'm trying to delete row with id=1 I would like to delete and id=2 How can I do this?" So you want that if you delete the row with ID 1 that the 'child' rows get deleted too?

Comment: The FK should handle that automaticly, if not try to look at the settings/definition of the FK there should be a option which provides your wanted feature.